# Clojure, metadata for a symbol

Tags: clojure, metadata

http://clojure.org/metadata says "Symbols and collections support metadata"

So I try to set metadata to a symbol:

```
=> a 
17 

=> (def aa ^a 'x) 

=> aa 
x 

=> (meta aa) 
nil
```

It does not work as I expected.

```
=> (def aa ^a []) 

=> (meta aa) 
{:tag 17}
```

This does.

Is this a mistake in the documentation? If not, can you please explain?

**Update** after answer by Arthur Ulfeldt: So I understand it as follows. When I wrote

```
(def aa ^a 'x)
```

the reader expanded it into

```
(def aa ^a (quote x))
```

so the metadata were at the list (quote x), and not at the symbol. When evaluating the def macro, this list got evaluated, leaving us with x, and the metadata were lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if instead of using the `quote` reader macro you write out the `(quote x)` expression and then attach the metadata to the symbol within the quote:

```
user> (def aa (quote ^unevaluated-symbol x))
#'user/aa

user> (meta aa)
{:tag unevaluated-symbol}
```

It's worth noting that when you put the symbol with the quote it never gets a chance to be evaluated. if you want it evaluated you can skip the whole quoting and generate the symbol with the `symbol` function:

```
user> (def aa  (with-meta (symbol "x") {:foo a}))
#'user/aa
user> (meta aa)
{:foo 17}
```